# Architecting a scalable SaaS Application

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, microservices, docker-swarm

I was recently introduced to microservices, and since I found it interesting, I thought to build a web app to get an hands-on on experience in microservices.

Lets say I have a SaaS blog application just like blogspot.com, where user can signup and create their own blog account. Each user will have their own url/subdomain, say http://john.example-blog.com (where example-blog.com is my main SaaS app)

Following are the features of example-blog.com app

A) The example-blog app is divided into the following parts, each one is housed inside a docker container.

- A User microservice (built with nodejs)
- A Post microservice (built with nodejs)
- A Comments microservice (built with nodejs)
- An Api Gateway (nginx reverse proxy) that routes all incoming api request and forwards them to the above services based on the api endpoint.

B) Each user would have their own database (MySQL). Which means each user will have 3 MySQL databases that the above 3 services will connect to.

Now, I have the following questions in my mind.

Q1) How will the application know which database to connect to based on the user's subdomain?

My thought: One option is to create a new config file every time a new user signs up. This config file can contain information about the user, for eg their database name or database connection string etc.

For eg. If a user signs up for a subdomain like john.example-blog.com, then a config file will be created in the /home  directory of the server say /home/john.example-blog.com.config.js

The application, based on the url will read its relavant config file and then connect to the database.

While the above solution seems okay to me, but say tomorrow my app started getting huge number of traffic and since I am using microservices, I can horizantally scale these into three diff servers

- Server 1 houses the User microservice
- Server 2 houses the Post microservice
- Server 3 houses the Comments microservice

Q1.1) Do I have to copy the same config file in those 3 servers?

Q1.2) If yes, what is the best way to automatically copy from one server to another?

Q1.3) If not, then how else should this be done?

Q2) Each time i create a new server, for eg, if I need to further scale the comments microservice to 2 new servers, do I have to manually update the new server's IP in the API Gateway?

Q3) I have heard there are solutions like kubernetes but I find it overwhelming and also think it would be an overkill for such small scale apps. Can the above be achieved without using third party applications like kubernetes or docker-swarm?

Q4) Are there any pitfalls in my architecture design?

Q5) Can you please point me to any article/tutorial that can answer my questions?

Architecture diagram of example-blog.com
[image]

Sorry for the long post, I am fairly new to microservices and would like to learn an efficient way to build and scale SaaS apps while keeping things as simple as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you consider to use Istio ? Take a look: https://events19.linuxfoundation.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Traffic-Management-and-Visibility-Infrastructure-for-Rapid-Microservice-Delivery-Eddie-Arrage-Huawei.pdf, https://istio.io/ ?

Comment: I will take a look into that, but is the above architecture not possible without using any third party tool?

Comment: Did you take a look at the documentation I have provided and Istio specification ?